# ScrollView inside ViewPager is not working when softkeyboard popsup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I have populated my Viewpager with two Fragments.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <in.mobme.chillr.views.flow.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:sldtab_textColorSelected="@color/light_black"
        app:sldtab_textColorUnselected="@color/black"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/tabs"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second fragment is wrapped around a ScrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="$"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="52sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_details_scroll"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rupee_icon"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="0"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:textSize="52sp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/remarks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="Remarks"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:maxLength="140"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/invoice_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/remarks"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="Reference ID"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>

</RelativeLayout></ScrollView>
```

When pressed on any of the Edittext, it it supposed to make the soft keyboard popup, and thus the scrollview should be active. I can get the ScrollView to work on few phones like the Samsung S4 Mini, Sony Ericcson L, etc. But it does not work on many others like Moto G, Moto E, Samsung S4, etc.

I have added the following parameter for the activity in Manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in ScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: sorry @Anitha Manikandhan , this does not help